# Using variables in Mailgun Templates in Node server

Tags: node.js, express, mailgun

I am trying to create a basic express route to handle my emailing templates and for some reason, I cannot get the variable names to pass into mailgun.  I have looked it up elsewhere, and have tried to input the variables into the data in every way possible and no matter what, when the email is received, the variable is completely blank.  Is there another way I am supposed to input the variables in my api request?

Express data being sent:

```
const data = {
  from: "Me <email@gmail.com>",
  to: "myEmail@live.com",
  subject: "Hello",
  template: "thank_you_email",
  recipient_name: "My Name",
  "v:recipient_name": "My Name",
  "h:X-Mailgun-Variables": JSON.stringify({
    recipient_name: "My Name",
  }),
};
```

As you can see in this code, I am trying to send over the variable in three different ways and still, it does not seem to be sent over, although the subject does work.

Here is the html template portion with this variable:

```
                                    <h3
                                      style="
                                        margin: 0;
                                        line-height: 24px;
                                        mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
                                        font-family: georgia, times,
                                          'times new roman', serif;
                                        font-size: 20px;
                                        font-style: normal;
                                        font-weight: normal;
                                        color: #24578e;
                                      "
                                    >
                                      Dear %recipient_name%,
                                    </h3>
```

Is there something I am missing here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the answer soon after posting this question, but I will not delete it, in case others are having problems.  In the email template, you must put variables in as

```
{{recipient_name}}
```

instead of

```
%recipient_name%
```

This is what seems to work instead; the only exception is when adding an unsubscribe button, you put in

```
%unsubscribe_url%
```

and mailgun will take care of the rest for you.